# bxSlider not sizing on re-size in Chrome (responsive issues)

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, bxslider

I was wondering if someone with a fresh set of eyes can see what I'm doing wrong here. I'm using the bxSlider and the images won't resize on the iPad and in Chrome. It's fine in Firefox. Here's the website: http://transcend.hostrainmaker.com/

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: which images? Works on chrome for me... Also post just the code that is causing the issue rather than a link to a website

Comment: Hey @stackErr! Sorry about this: 

`<ul class="bxslider">
<li><img src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/assets/images/SLIDER_TEXT_01.png" /></li>
<li><img src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/assets/images/SLIDER_TEXT_02.png" /></li>
</ul>`

The only CSS I am using is: 
`.bx-wrapper img{margin:0 auto;}`

The rest of the CSS for the bx-slider is the default where you can view here: 
http://transcend.hostrainmaker.com/themes/TranscendEG/assets/jquery.bxslider.css

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems working fine here. You're probably trying to see if it changes the image size by resizing the window of the browser. This plugin sets width of list items according to initial screen size, doesn't utilize media queries or js to resize it. If you want, you may add media queries yourself.

Comment: Really? The images when I resize the page don't resize like they do in Firefox. And the slider on the bxSlider home page, does the way it's supposed to. Here's what I'm seeing: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/f99yfbk8f90vxek/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-12%20at%2012.18.23%20PM.png[/link]

Comment: Yep. It's same in Firefox as Chrome - http://prntscr.com/2rxoyx Did you check Firefox's console? Is it blocking any script or do you see any other errors?

Comment: On the contrary, as I noted above, it opens fine on all devices given user doesn't attempt to resize the screen. Checked on my phone as well as tab, opens fine unless you switch between portrait/landscape.

Comment: Hey Nix! That's the kicker. It's weird. But the bxSlider on the main page http://bxslider.com/ works just fine in Chrome. :-S

Comment: It can possibly be a conflict because of the other script you're using to manipulate background image of the container. Did you try without that?

Comment: I actually took it back to the default (just a normal slider with no settings) and it was doing the same thing.

Comment: Then it must be some other thing interfering with plugin's JS as plugin is not able to assign new width when screen resizes. I tried, but couldn't find anything in particular. A workaround would be assigning width with `!important` property to those list items using media queries as per the screen size, so that it will ignore the width assigned by slider's JS.

Comment: Hahah!! I tried that and weirdly enough, the width is already set at a very large scale so the 100% isn't working (the image just goes off the edge of the screen). And it's something in the code somewhere because I created a stripped down version of the slider and it's just fine. Bah!! Darn CSS. Thanks for your help Nix!